# Taxonomy Field ispathrendered property

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

All i want to do is display the full path of my Taxonomy field....Simple!

I've added this little snippet of XML to my `<ArrayOfProperty>` within the field i want to apply this property to.

```
   <Property>
      <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
      <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value>
    </Property>
```

All the settings of the field seems to be applied, I've checked via the GUI and SharePoint mananger and it seems to be applied!

However the does not show the full path....

When i go in to the GUI and save the field all works !?!?!?!

My question is why do i have to go in after my deployment and save the field to get this setting to apply?

Answer (score 1):

Although I also would like to know how to do this in XML, there is an alternative: you can handle it in a feature receiver by setting the `IsPathRendered` property on a `TaxonomyField` instance.

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent)
        {
            Guid fieldId = new Guid("{YOUR-FIELD'S-GUID-GOES-HERE}");
            TaxonomyField field = site.RootWeb.Fields[fieldId] as TaxonomyField;

            // Render full taxonomy path, not just the leaf.
            field.IsPathRendered = true;

            field.Update();
        }
    }
```